# Highcharts Plotband with label climbs up column when moving left navigator handle

Tags: jquery, highcharts

This is an interesting problem and I don't know how to fix it. I have a rather complex chart that I am using to map points on a date series with Highcharts Highstock. Everything works great except when you move the left pane on the navigator, the plotband label starts to move up the plotband line. Here is the fiddle and sample code for the plot band (full source in the fiddle). I should also mention that this only happens when you close the gap of the navigator, ie, move "in" the left navigator handle.

http://jsfiddle.net/chas688/w3KV9/

```
plotBands: [{
      color: '#2B6D97',
      width: 2,
      value: new Date().getTime(),
      label: {
        text: "(Today)",
        verticalAlign: 'Top',
        rotation: 0,
        style: {
          color: '#2B6D97',
          fontWeight: 'bold'
        },
        x: -25,
        y: 60
      }            
    }]
```

Thanks!

Comment: It's bug for 1.3.10 version of Highstock, already reported [here](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/2827).

Comment: Thanks, I tried to extend the axis, but kept getting errors. I'll wait for the update as well.

Comment: You can always use 1.3.9 version - which works properly.

Comment: That seemed to have fixed it - yes - updated fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/chas688/w3KV9/4/